# How to validate phone number length with same method as firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication, phone-number

I need check that phone number have valid length to create firebase account.

> Firebase may trow exeptions:
>
> **errorInfo: { code: 'auth/invalid-phone-number', message: 'TOO_LONG' }**
>
> **errorInfo: { code: 'auth/invalid-phone-number', message: 'TOO_SHORT' }**

And question is: "how validate phone number before request to firebase?"

*What algorithm does firebase use to validate a phone? The fact is that according to the [standart E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164), the phone can be from 7 to 14 digits long, so the regular expression is not suitable. Phone number length depends from country.*

Comment: In most countries, hardly anyone uses E.164 when writing their own phone number. Instead you should use Google's own `libphonenumber` to validate the number entirely without relying on arbitrary (and easily bypassed) length checks.

Comment: What language or environment are you using? Is this for an Internet-facing web-application, an Electron / PhoneGap / Cordova application, or something else?

Comment: @Dai i'm use javascript, i mean validation on client, but have nodejs server

Comment: @Dai looks like this is my solution: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-phone-number-input , thank you.